# Create user that can only shutdown?

Tags: user-management

Is there any possibility of creating a user, that can ONLY shutdown PC, but cannot write, read, use any other console, or command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last field in the /etc/passwd file for a user is the program run upon login, usually a shell like /bin/bash.  Replace that /bin/bash with /sbin/poweroff, and you have a user that can only login, which runs the poweroff.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822) is what you are looking for. Keep in mind, you need to create a shutdown rule in /etc/sudoers for that specific user with the following content:

```
user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
```

or for passwordless:

```
user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
```

Also you need the change the homefolder permissions to read-only.